# troubles with creating objects in java

Tags: java, object

Hello So I have a entire class called tractor with different data's stored in it but now I'm suppose to create an object call tractor with a zero parameter constructor but This is the code I have so far and its giving em errors

First off this my Tractor Class which is in a different file:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Tractor
{
   private int RentalRate;
   private int RentalDays;
   private int VehicleID;
   private int RentalProfit;

    public void setRentalRate(int r)
    {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("What's the Rental Rate?");
      int num = input.nextInt();
      num = r;
      if(r<0 || r >1000)

         RentalRate = r;

         RentalRate= 1;  
    } 

    public int getRentalRate() 
    {
      return RentalRate;
    }  

    public void setVehicleID(int v)
    {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("What's the vehicleID?");
      int num1 = input.nextInt();
      num1 = v;
      if(v<0)

         VehicleID = v;

         VehicleID = 1;    
    }

    public int getVehicleID()
    {
      return VehicleID;  
    }

    public void setRentalDays(int d)
    {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("How many rental days?");
      int num2 = input.nextInt();
      num2 = d;
      if(d<0)

         RentalDays = d;

         RentalDays = 1;    
    }

    public int getRentalDays()
    {
      return RentalDays;
    }



     public String toString() 
     {
       String str;
       str = "RentalDays:" + RentalDays +"\nRenalRate:" + RentalRate + "\nVehicleID " + VehicleID; 
       return str;      
     }


    public void RentalProfit(int RentalRate, int RentalDays)  
    {
      RentalProfit = RentalRate * RentalDays; 
    }
```

}

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class testTractor
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      public tractor()
      {
         this.RentalDays = d;
         this.RentalRate = r;
         this.VehicleID = v;
      }
 }
}
```

The error is :

```
testTractor.java:7: error: illegal start of expression
      public tractor()
      ^
testTractor.java:7: error: ';' expected
      public tractor()
                      ^
2 errors
```

Comment: Your code is not valid Java and you should start over. You create Tractor objects by declaring a variable and assigning it an object, the latter usually by **calling** a constructor: `Tractor tractor = new Tractor();`. But more importantly your question suggests that you'd benefit from reading the first chapter or two of any intro to Java textbook since these are first principles that you're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

You have compilation errors. You need to first declare the Tractor class then add the constructor inside it. One way to do is declare in a separate file. Also in Java unless you had defined `d` you couldnt have assigned it. Maybe you wanted to assign the day as a `String` look in the examples I provide below.
You need to to first create a file call Tractor.java and then define variables there. For example contents of `Tractor.java`:

```
  public class Tractor {
    String rentaldays,someOtherValue;

    public Tractor(){
        rentaldays ="monday";
        someOtherValue="value";
    }
    //or
    public Tractor(String rentalDays){
        this.rentaldays = rentalDays;
        someOtherValue = "asf";
    }
}
```

Then in your main method You can do `Tractor trac = new Tractor();` or `Tractor trac = new Tractor("tuesday");` also after that you can print the rentaldays of `trac` using `System.out.println(trac.rentaldays);`

From the looks of it you will probably be making a tractor rental system. In that case, rentalDays may be an array of Strings. And then you would have an array of Tractor objects to store in the rental system. You can look at these terms and keywords to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Well the thing is I have an entire class called Tractor.java which is a Tractor class with all the variables such at RetanlRate = r and such, I'm just not sure how to think the two programs together so that my main testTractor.java uses all of the information I got from my factor class in a different java program

Comment: That looks good now add a constructor like  I did for tractor to initialize your variables. Then use the `Tractor trac = new Tractor();` to initialize the tractor object. That constructor goes in your Tractor class. When these files are in the same folder or "package", you don't need to import them. But if they were in different packages or folders. You would need to specify where the other one is i.e import the class

Answer (score 0):

You are defining it wrong, define your methods inside class then call them in main() method.

```
class Test{

public void greeting(){
System.out.print("hello to JAVA..");
}
public static void main(String[] args){
Test testObj = new Test();
testObj.greeting();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you use an illegal of java syntax, if you already have class tractor in your project. for calling it to in other class, try below code

```
    public class TestTractor(){
       Tractor objTractor;
       public static void main(String[] args){
          //create new tractor object with no parameter
          objTractor = new Tractor();
          //create new tractor object with parameter
          objTractor = new Tractor(parameter here);
          //do some action of object here
          ...........
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

//This is just a sample

in your tractor class add below code

```
  public tractor()
  {
     this.RentalDays = d;
     this.RentalRate = r;
     this.VehicleID = v;
  }
```

And keep your TestTractor class as

```
public class TestTractor(){
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Tractor  objTractor = new Tractor();
      // objTractor.yourMethodName
  }
}
```